# How can I prevent my background video from expanding further than a section?

Tags: html, css

I have three sections, but my background video height is too high within the first section.  In return, this cuts off a portion of the section below.  So basically I just need my video container to be the same size as my first section. Any thoughts?

I tried changing the max height, removing the section all together and various other css properties but my video height is still too big.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

section#home {
  width: 100% height: 100%;
}

section#work {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515724684585- 
 ec93c008b8b5?ixlib=rb- 1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1875&q=80") 
 no-repeat center center/cover;
}

section#contact {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487131765602- 
 9c2220588c4d?ixlib=rb- 1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3451&q=80") 
 no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.work_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.video_container video {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <header>V E R T E X // D R O N E S</header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#contact"></a>Contact</li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="home">
    <div class="video_container"></div>
    <video src="drone.mp4" loop autoplay muted></video>
  </section>
  <section id="work">
    <div class="work_container"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="contact"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: shouldn't the `video` be inside the `.video_container` div in the html ?

Comment: Your snippet is utterly invalid and, as of now, is unable to display the described problem. Biggest issues: `<a>` tags are not closed, there's a space in one of the font links and the link to your `.mp4` is relative, hence invalid on [so]. Also, you're placing CSS code outside of `<html>` which could never get parsed. If you need help, make sure those issues are all fixed.

Comment: @GabrielePetrioli that is one option I tried and it still would not work for me.  I am a beginner so I am sure it is something easy I'm missing here.

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu thank you, I fixed the tags and font. Unfortunately I cannot link the video and only have it stored locally.  I am not sure what you mean by the css being outside the <html> tag.  Could you please tell me where?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the video be 100% `width` and `height` and use `object-fit` to set if it should fill the container (*possibly cropping part of the video*) using `cover` as the value, or if it should contain the whole video (*no cropping, but might add letterboxing*) by using the `contain` value.

```css
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

#work {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1515724684585-ec93c008b8b5?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=1875&q=80") no-repeat center center/cover;
}

#contact {
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1487131765602-9c2220588c4d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=3451&q=80") no-repeat center center/cover;
}

.work_container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

#home video {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit:cover; /*or contain*/
}
```

```html
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oleo+Script" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo+2:400,700" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
family=Amatic+SC:400,700" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="container">
  <nav class="navbar">
    <header>V E R T E X // D R O N E S</header>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#work">Work</a></li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <section id="home">
    <video src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4" loop autoplay muted></video>
  </section>
  <section id="work">
    <div class="work_container"></div>
  </section>
  <section id="contact"></section>
</div>
```

Comment: That fixed it.  Thank you so much.  I realize I tried all those and it was simply a syntax error with the #home video properties.